# Максимальный таймаут HTTP соединения в Android

Tags: android, http

Какой максимально возможный таймаут может быть установлен для HTTP соединения под Android?

Использую стандартный `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рискну и порассуждаю.

Абстрактный класс HttpURLConnection расширяется от абстрактного класса URLConnection, в котором находится метод [setConnectTimeout()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout()). Согласно описанию передача нулевого значения интерпретируется как бесконечный тайм-аут. Отсюда ответ на вопрос. Максимально возможным тайм-аутом будет бесконечный тайм-аут.

С другой стороны методу передается int, который согласно [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2)

> For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive

2147483647 ms = 2 147 483,647 секунд = 35 791,394116666666666666666666667 минут = 596,52323527777777777777777777778 часов = 24,855134803240740740740740740741 суток